# Jenkins deployment to K8 cluster

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy my docker image into kubernetes cluster in first time, i have two nodes master and worker nodes both are up and running status.

I have created namesapace pre-release environment to deploy my changes on it, during jenkins build, i am getting below error.

```
+ kubectl '--kubeconfig=****' '--context=K8sCluster-CC-pre-release' apply -f ./environment/pre-release '-n=pre-release'
error: context "K8sCluster-CC-pre-release" does not exist
```

Jenkins stage

```
stage('deployment') {
        container('kubectl') {

            withCredentials([kubeconfigFile(credentialsId: 'KUBERNETES_CLUSTER_CONFIG', variable: 'KUBECONFIG')]) {
            def kubectl
                if(gitBranch == "future-master-fix") {
                kubectl = "kubectl --kubeconfig=${KUBECONFIG} --context=K8sCluster-CC-pre-release"
                sh "${kubectl} apply -f ./environment/pre-release -n=pre-release"
                }   
            }
        }
      }
```

```
kubectl config set-context K8sCluster-CC-pre-release --namespace=K8sCluster-CC-pre-release --user=kubernetes-admin --cluster=kubernetes
Context "K8sCluster-CC-pre-release" created.
```

```
CURRENT   NAME                          CLUSTER      AUTHINFO           NAMESPACE
*         K8sCluster-CC-pre-release     kubernetes   kubernetes-admin   K8sCluster-CC-pre-release
```

can you please someone help me on this ?

Comment: Jenkins is unable to find the context `K8sCluster-CC-pre-release`. Where is it defined?

Comment: I have created name space in master machine like pre-release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `K8sCluster-CC-pre-release` context does not exist in your kubeconfig file. You can run `kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.current-context}'` to check current context and use that context.

Comment: Hi Arghya, i have created context but still its failing with same error

Comment: how did you create the context?

Comment: kubectl config set-context K8sCluster-CC-pre-release --namespace=K8sCluster-CC-pre-release --user=kubernetes-admin --cluster=kubernetes

Comment: since this is your current context...you can just do kubectl apply

Comment: sure, let me edit my jenkins file and i will do the rebuild again.

Comment: Do you mean like this, sh "kubectl apply -f ./infrastructure/pre-release -n=pre-release"

Comment: HI Arghya, thanks for your help, i am all set now using above command